# What is this unruly pink-purple flower?

Tags: identification, flowers

Very funy shape, attractive to wildlife:

https://chapollinator.org/wp-content/uploads/photo-gallery/Lookout_Mountain_1.jpg

https://chapollinator.org/wp-content/uploads/photo-gallery/Garden_Hero_3.jpg

https://chapollinator.org/wp-content/uploads/photo-gallery/Garden_Hero.jpg

Comment: Nice pictures. It could be helpful to add some pictures of the leaves and whole plant as well. Also the location would help, hummingbirds imply new world, right?

Comment: These links appear to point to images from a website about Chattanooga, Tennessee. Likely no further images available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's actually Liatris squarrosa. The open "button" flowers (as opposed to the more often seen purple spikes) are one of its characteristics

[Liatris squarrosa in Tennessee](http://www.easttennesseewildflowers.com/gallery/var/resizes/Summer-Roadsides-Pink/DSCN0005.jpg?m=1348888388)

[Liatris squarrosa habit](http://easywildflowers.com/quality/lia.sq1.jpg)

Another characteristic is the scaly flower bracts, shown clearly in the first photo. It all the scales were out and then downward-pointing (like a collie's ears), then it might be L. ligulistylis.

It's relatively small for a liatris, and somewhat later blooming than most. For example, in my garden in southern Wisconsin, L. spicata is just finished, L. ligulistylis is starting, L. cylindracea is in mid-bloom, and L. punctata and L. squarrosa haven't begun blooming yet.

Comment: I think you are right. I withdrew my suggestion. Good call.

Comment: "... L. spicata ... L. ligulistylis ... L. cylindracea ... L. punctata .. L. squarrosa ..." :-o :-o :-o  Jaw-dropper!

Comment: @VividD No kidding!  Liatris is one of my favorite genus of perennials!  Jurp, what a 'name dropper' huh?  I've got this giggle that won't stop!  Jurp!  which is your favorite?

Comment: @Storm - I only knew L. spicata until I began working at The Flower Factory, where they had/have over ten different liatris (and 2500+ other perennials). It was a great place to work. I thought I knew perennials until I started there. Very humbling at first.   L. ligulistylis is probably my favorite, because it tends to have strong stems, bloom for a long time, and is a monarch magnet. The monarchs sold the plants for us - sometimes five or six on just one or two blooming scapes. They occasionally even went home with our customers.

Comment: How cool the monarchs helped you sell these plants, too cute! Wonderful story.